# Nodemon is not working: How can i resolve it?

Tags: nodemon

I have installed nodemon globally(npm i -g nodemon), I get the message that nodemon is properly installed:

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

When i run it i get the message :
nodemon' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

Comment: pardon my french but have you tried restarting your terminal?

Comment: Yes, it's still not working

Comment: have you installed it with sudo? if so you can probably only run it with sudo

Answer (score 0):

To check that is it really installed on you system use `nodemon -h` command or with `sudo nodemon -h`. If it only responded when tried with sudo, that means you should run it with sudo from now on.

You can use it in a different way without the need for such a mess. First remove it by using `npm uninstall -g nodemon` command.

It is recommended to use Nodemon only for development purposes. So that means it is dev tool and you don't need it install as main dependencies.

So, you can basically install it as dev dependencies using this command: `npm install --save-dev nodemon`.

Then change the scripts (package.json):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
},
```

Now when you just `npm start` the script will work.